# Assign API response to static class in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, static, unmarshalling

I am writing a service in Spring Boot. Inside my service, I have to call an API which will return a JSON. I want to unmarshal the JSON to a **static class object**. I know how to unmarshal to a normal (non static class), but I can't figure out how to do it for static class.

Comment: What do you want to do with it (the unmarshalled static object)? Why does it need to be static in your opinion? Maybe something different than a static class can accomplish the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve if you explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @kwkw Actually, I have to call the API only once when my service starts and then use the data (like public key etc) to encrypt the requests which my service will get. To accomplish this, I have put call to API in main class and I want to use the data in RestController class where requests will hit my service. So, I want to use static class to store the received data so that I can access it anywhere in the project